# Paso de variables

Tags: php, mvc, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema similar a CodeIgniter para pasar variables de un controlador a una vista. Os voy a poner un ejemplo.

**Controlador:**

```
class Welcome extends MF_Controller
{   
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        global $prueba;
        $prueba = 'hola';
        $this->setSubtitle('Welcome');
        $this->addView('welcome.php');
    }
}
```

**Vista:**

```
<div class="container my-4 py-4">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>This is a index page.</p>
    <?php echo $prueba; ?>
</div>
```

En la práctica es lo siguiente: El controlador se encarga de definir la variable y cargar la vista con un *include*. Después estoy usando esa variable dentro del propio include.

Todo carga correctamente excepto la variable *$prueba*, que me da el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: prueba in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mframe\public\view\welcome.php on line 4

¿A qué se puede deber? Muchísimas gracias.

### Edit:

Agrego esto a petición (Repito, no es CodeIgniter, es un sistema propio pero estoy dándole una forma similar a CI). No está todo pero si lo necesario para que se entienda. La cuestión es que la view si carga, solo falla la variable:

```
class MF_Controller
{

    private $view;
    
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = array();
    }

    public function addView($name)
    {
        if(!in_array($name, $this->view))
        {
            array_push($this->view, $name);
        }
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        header('Content-type: text/html');
        echo DOCTYPE . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<html lang="' . LANGUAGE . '">' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<head>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<meta charset="' . CHARSET . '"/>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="public/assets/img/favicon.png"/>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" href="public/assets/img/favicon.png"/>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="public/assets/img/favicon.png"/>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '</head>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<body>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<header>' . PHP_EOL;
        include 'public/layouts/header.php';
        echo PHP_EOL . '</header>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<main>' . PHP_EOL;
        for($i=0; $i < count($this->view); $i++)
        {
            include 'public/view/' . $this->view[$i];
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo '</main>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<footer>' . PHP_EOL;
        include 'public/layouts/footer.php';
        echo PHP_EOL . '</footer>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '</body>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '</html>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrias [edit] y agregar la definición de `MF_Controller` o del método `addView`? Hasta donde yo se, no son CodeIgniter

Comment: @Marcos listo. No, no es codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solucionado.

Lo arreglé de esta forma.

**Controlador:**

```
class Welcome extends MF_Controller
{   
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->prueba = 'hola';
        $this->setSubtitle('Welcome');
        $this->addView('welcome.php');
    }
}
```

**Vista:**

```
<div class="container my-4 py-4">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>This is a index page.</p>
    <?php echo $this->prueba; ?>
</div>
```

Basta con definir y llamar a la variable con *$this->prueba*.

Comment: A modo de comentario, vas a tener que tener mucho cuidado con el nombre de las variables, no vaya ser cosa que por error sobre-escribas una utilizada por el `controller`

Comment: en lugar de un $this->prueba, podrias pasarle un array asociativo, tipo $this->parameters. De esta manera, en tu plantilla podrias acceder a $this->parameters['indice'] (por ej). Asi si tu plantilla necesita mas variables, sabes que estan en ese array.